# no method matching setindex : trying to change matrix values

Tags: julia

Using Julia, I've defined a 9x10 matrix of zeros, and am trying to change a single entry , but I get the error `'setindex!' has no method matching setindex!(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64)`

My code is:

```
m = zeros(9,10)
m[1][1] = 1.0
```

with the error pointing to the second line. `typeof(m)` is an `Array{Float64,2}`, which, as far as I can tell is mutable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To index 2-dimensional arrays, just use `m[1,1]`.

The syntax `m[1][1]` would be valid for a 1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional arrays.

```
m = zeros(9,10)
m[1,1] = 1.0

m = Array[ [1,2], [3,4,5] ]
m[1][1]
```

Comment: `getindex` method is defined for Number type as: `getindex(x::Number, i::Integer) = i == 1 ? x : throw(BoundsError())` so the syntax m[ind][1] is valid when use to get value. but it is not true for `setindex!`

Comment: That's because you can't change the value assigned to an immutable quantity like a number.